# Drawing Graphs with Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, graph, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I wanted to start using Compose Multiplatform and now I need to draw a Graph with it, so something like the following picture, but the style could be different

[image: Graph I want to draw]

I mean I could do it with a canvas and draw it manually but since I wanted to add nodes  dynamically, it would be pretty tedious.

Is there a better way for drawing such graphs?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to draw such lines. I'm sure it wouldn't be tedious if you extract the repetitive code in methods/extensions

Comment: @PylypDukhov Yeah but if i add additional nodes, the spacing between all of them has to be adjusted which is tedious. The line drawing can be done with functions etc i know

Comment: you could've get each view position using `Modifier.onPlaced`, and use these points to draw lines, but I'd prefer drawing everything by hand, as math is quite simple here